# Warning about using logical && between constant in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, warnings

I use this code to compare two strings:

```
NSComparisonResult result = [cellTitle compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch && NSLiteralSearch)];
```

but xcode shows warning about using logical && and offers to use bitwise &, by bitwise & the comparison don't return correct result.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to combine two parts of a bitmask. You can use the bitwise OR or XOR operators, or an addition for this - `|`, `^` or `+`. The norm would be `|`.

Comment: In this case, he'll want to use bitwise OR (`|`)

Comment: @Dave - why? They're members of a genuine bitmask, so the three are equivalent. I agree it's probably the one I'd normally use out of habit, but they all work.

Comment: You're right that all three will work here. But you almost never see `^` or `+` used in this context, so using them here could lead to confusion in the future.

Comment: Agreed. So using `|` is preferable rather than necessary. Have added a comment to this effect.

Comment: In what way? Error message, undesired behaviour? In either case, details needed...

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing:

```
 NSComparisonResult result = [cellTitle compare:searchText 
                            options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSLiteralSearch)];
```

Those flags are a binary numbers with only one 1 set. So when you do a logical |, you get the "mix" of both (Ex: 1000 | 0100 => 1100), that way you can set several flags as options.